# Huawei Secospace USG 2000 on a non Default Port

Tags: networking, ipsec, network-protocols

I would like to know which is the default port of IPSec. I have tried to connect on all default ports, but I was unsuccessful. Also, I have applied NMap to them, but have no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, ISAKMP key exchange takes place on UDP/500.  IPSec in encapsulating-security-payload mode has its own protocol number (50) so the question of "*ports*" does not apply.  IPSec in NAT-traversal mode often uses UDP/4500, but unless you're sure you're in NAT-T mode, this will not apply.

The first problem with port scanning, even for the ISAKMP subsystem, is that it's not TCP, so you can't take advantage of the three-way handshake to confirm that it's listening *before* any protocol-related issues could possibly have arisen.  Moreover, many IPSec appliances are configured to completely ignore requests that are not from peers to whom they are configured to talk, or traffic that isn't appropriate to the protocol.  This is ostensibly for "*security*" reasons, but really it's a major PITA, and it may account for why your `nmap` scan reveals nothing.

In the case of some very twitchy Checkpoint firewalls I once had to peer with, as soon as an IPSec proposal was made which contained **anything** with which they were unhappy (in this case, one side wanted compression on, and the other did not) they went "dead in the water" - completely silent - instead of negotiating alternative connection parameters, despite the peers being well known to them.  Had it not been for a **very** good checkpoint engineer at C&W, and her deft usage of high-level C&W executives to lean on Nokia, I don't think we would *ever* have found out why their Checkpoints kept going silent on us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, MadHatter. My first mistake was to assume that the communication used TCP on the ISAKMP key exchange. That's because of my equipment features. Its biggest selling point is the firewall. So, it would be easier to track sessions using TCP. But you're right. Reading a bit more on the Internet, I found out that UDP is the most used transport layer protocol on this matter. So, even though I have not found out yet if it is used as default on this device, it has the most probability. I'll follow your steps and check out whether or not I'm facing the same issues as you.